# Explaining the contents of the ~/.profile file

Tags: .profile

```bsh
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Can anyone explain the contents of the `~/.profile` file? So when you enter into the `~/.profile` file what does all the writing mean?

Comment: See also http://stefaanlippens.net/bashrc_and_others and http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/6.3/postlfs/profile.html and

Comment: @bodhi.zazen How is the linked question a duplicate of this question? They're asking to explain what `~/.profile` does (not to mention `~/.profile` != `~/.bash_profile`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplified version:

```bsh
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

This parts checks wheter `~/.profile` itself is being sourced by a Bash instance, and if that's the case sources in turn `~/.bashrc`; this is  a way to include the user's settings stored in `~/.bashrc` e.g. also in login shells, which normally don't source `~/.bashrc`;

```bsh
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

This part checks whether `~/bin` exists, and if that's the case prepends `~/bin` to the current value of `$PATH`; this is done so that potential executables / scripts present in `~/bin` take precedence over executables / scripts present in other paths included in `$PATH` (e.g. by placing an executable named `cat` in `~/bin`, when running `cat` that executable would be run in place of the usual `/bin/cat`).

---

Detailed version:

```bsh
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

This part checks whether the expansion of `$BASH_VERSION` has a non-zero lenght (`if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]`), and if that's the case, if the expansion of `$HOME/.bashrc` exists and is a regular file (`if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]`), the expansion of `$HOME/.bashrc` is sourced.

Since Bash sets `$BASH_VERSION` upon invocation, checking whether `$BASH_VERSION` has a non-zero lenght is a robust way of determining whether the file itself is being sourced by a Bash instance.

This is why when invoking Bash as a login shell on Ubuntu the user's settings stored in `~/.bashrc` are included (this is not necessarily the case for other distributions); Bash itself only sources `~/.profile` when invoked as a login shell, and this is a way to go around that;

```bsh
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

This part checks whether the expansion of `$HOME/bin` exists and is a directory (`if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ]`), and if that's the case prepends the expansion of `$HOME/bin` to the current value of `$PATH` (`PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"`; `$HOME` is normally set to the user's home directory).

This is done so that potential executables / scripts present in the expansion of `$HOME/bin` take precedence over executables / scripts present in other paths included in `$PATH`.

Comment: Is there any you can simplify what you have written? I have only just started looking into Ubuntu

Comment: @JansenRoy I tried to simplify it a bit. Any better? If there's something specific you don't understand feel free to ask.

Comment: Thank you for the help so far...but I do not understand most of the language used and also do not know much about bash and the profile file

Comment: @JansenRoy Perhaps you should start here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html. If you have more specific questions check if they've been asked before on the site and check the related answers, that should help; I'm happy to help with a specific concern, but it'd be too extensive (both for the comments section and for the chat) to address all the basics. If you have a specific question about `~/.profile` you can drop by the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) and ping me there with `@kos`, I'm lurking there most of the times.

Comment: if you don't know much about bash or profile, just leave the file alone. It has it's reason to be there. When starting to get apt with linux and bash you automatically acquire an understanding