# Ubuntu 14.04 - User desktop launcher is missing

Tags: 14.04, unity, launcher

The same question has been asked before, but the answers that I found *did not work for me*, so I'm asking a new question.

I'm the main user and only sudoer on this computer, and **everything works for me**.

The **second user account** on this machine for no reason that I can think of, **no longer displays the launcher sidebar or top bar**, neither does <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> work. Icons are normally displayed on the desktop (in most other related questions like this the desktop is blank).

So I've found and tried so far:

- rebooting
- `sudo service lightdm restart`
- `unity --replace`
- `unity --reset-icons`
- `apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`
- `apt-get install --reinstall lightdm`
- remove files under /home/USER/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig
- starting ccsm from tty to enable unity plugin

`unity` reset commands return "no display variable set" and "compiz core couldn't open display 0".

When I try to launch unity from tty with `DISPLAY=:0 unity` I get the following:

```
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keycompiz (core) - Fatal: couldn't open display :0
```

Which sounds like it could be relevant?

How to restore desktop panels?

Comment: try the answer, it's worked for me https://askubuntu.com/questions/760825/cannot-boot-system-due-to-start-job-running-for-hold

Comment: Thanks karel, unfortunately much of what is there is outdated/deprecated, and I found no solution.  I'll update the question in a second.

Comment: I you create a new user account do you have the same issue that you are reporting with "the second user account"?

Comment: @ElderGeek Nope, when I make a new account it works as expected.

Comment: That sounds like an issue with that particular users profile then. You may find [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/751056/explaining-the-contents-of-the-profile-file) useful.

Answer (score -1):

the source : [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears/76951#76951)

You just need to turn the Unity plugin back on. The problem is this is a pain in the bottom because you've now got no graphical method to do this. So:

1. Try to open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
   This may not work but you can try right clicking on the desktop and selecting "Open terminal here." Otherwise, you may need to change to a "hard" terminal by pressing
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and log in.
2. Install `compizconfig-settings-manager` by running

   ```
   sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
   ```
3. Then run it with this:

   ```
   DISPLAY=:0 ccsm &
   ```

   The first part tells the terminal which display you want it to load on (otherwise it won't have a clue).
4. If you switched to a TTY in step 1, switch back to the graphical server by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> sometimes).
   There there should be a CompizConfig Settings Manager waiting for you.
5. Find the Unity plugin. Enable it. You will be asked "Ubuntu Unity Plugin requires the plugin OpenGL. Enable Ubuntu Unity Plugin / Enable OpenGL"
6. Everything should spring into life but if it doesn't, you might have to restart. You can do that by going back to the terminal and running `sudo reboot`.

Comment: I get Gtkwarning:could not open display, and AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_default_screen'

Comment: I can open ccsm from tty when logged into my own account though. But not when I'm logged in to the problem account.

Comment: look at this thread : https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1866462

Comment: Please delete one of your answers or merge them. Only under very rare circumstances should you create two separate answers to the same question.

Comment: I was able to start ccsm after `export DISPLAY=:0.0` but enabling the unity plugin did nothing for me.